# How to get AWS lambda $LATEST evaluated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I only keep the latest two versions of a lambda.

If I do:

```sh
$ aws lambda publish-version --function-name private-eye-converter-dev-pe-convert
```

I can see that the latest version is `"Version": "27",`.

But when I do:

```sh
$ aws lambda invoke --function-name my_lambda --cli-binary-format raw-in-base64-out \
--payload  '{"key": "value"}' out --log-type Tail --query 'LogResult' \
--output text |  base64 -d

START RequestId: f2bbdba7-c25b-460c-b72c-6c9afbf8afe0 Version: $LATEST
...
```

I got `Version: $LATEST`, which is helpless for me.

Is there a way of this `$LATEST` to show `27`?

Sure

```sh
$ aws lambda invoke --function-name my_lambda:27
```

does, but I don't know which version is the latest a priori.

Answer (score 1):

$LATEST is always the current, muttable version of the Lambda function. Sort of like a development version.

When you do Publish, you save all the current code and Lambda configuration to the function version, which you see as a version number.

The easiest way for you to always invoke the latest published version is to create an [ALIAS for the Lambda function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-aliases.html)

When you do `aws lambda publish` in the response, you will receive the version number. You can use that to pass it in the second command
`aws lambda update-alias` ([AWS CLI reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/lambda/update-alias.html))and that way you automatically update the alias to the latest version. Then, when you invoke the lambda function with `mylambda:myalias` it will show the latest version number in logs.

Comment: I read about it but your explanation is clearer and more succinct. Let me test this before approving your answer.

Comment: This "response" has nothing to the question. Yes, it tells about known facts such as `$LATEST` is the alias to the recent version. As for the `aws lambda publish` approach it could work only for a single developer in a single environment.